# Get status of thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running a thread in which mail is being sent. How can I know that a thread has completed its execution?

```
new Thread(x => SendMail(node.Attributes["id"].Value.ToString(), node["fname"].InnerText +      " " + node["lname"].InnerText, 500, node["email"].InnerText)).Start();
```

Comment: Are you using .NET 4? If so, using `Task` would be a better idea IMO.

Comment: You need to know a status of a Thread or whether `SendMail` method was called and exited?

Comment: While doing other work, I need to get notified that whether this thread has completed its execution or not and give message to user that your task has been completed

Comment: And if .Net 4 is not an option, you can use the [old school delegate `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx), with a potential `ManualResetEvent` to create asynchronous code. This worked from the first version of .Net.

Comment: Sample here: http://ideone.com/XGWPz6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside Andrew's Answer you can use BackgroundWorker It has already has RunWorkerCompleted event
[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
var thr = new Thread(x => SendMail(node.Attributes["id"].Value.ToString(), node["fname"].InnerText +      " " + node["lname"].InnerText, 500, node["email"].InnerText));
thr.Start();
thr.Join();//In this place main thread will wait
```

Answer (score 2):

You should keep a reference to the thread instance you create and then check the [`ThreadState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx). You can also check the [`IsAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) property to see if the thread is currently executing or not.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your environment is. You can, for example, avoid at all Threads by using Tasks and subscribing to the continuation.

e.g.

```
var task = Task.Run(DoSomething)
               .ContinueWith(a => Whatever())
```

Or by using the convenience keywords given by C# 5:

```
var task = await Task.Run(DoSomething);
Whatever();
```

If you MUST use threads I recommend to pass a delegate and when the e-mail has finished you have just to call it:

```
// Outside the thread
private Action callback;

// Before starting the thread
callback = MyMethod/*Or a lambda if you want*/;

// In the thread action
Action<object> threadBody = x => 
{
    SendMail(node.Attributes["id"].Value.ToString(), node["fname"].InnerText +      " " + node["lname"].InnerText, 500, node["email"].InnerText);
    callback();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation is to use the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` in combination with `ManualResetEvent`:

Such as:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    List<ManualResetEvent> events = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

    //in case you need to loop through multiple email addresses 
    //use the foreach here, assuming that the items is a list.

    //foreach(var item in items)
    //{
    var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(arg =>
    {
        SendMail(node.Attributes["id"].Value.ToString(), 
           node["fname"].InnerText + " " + node["lname"].InnerText,
           500, node["email"].InnerText);
        resetEvent.Set();
    });
    events.Add(resetEvent);

    //} <- closes the foreach loop

    //WaitHandle.WaitAll waits for all the threads to finish.
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray());
    MessageBox.Show("Mails are sent", "Notification");
}
```

This would be especially usefull in case you want to loop through a list or array of email-addresses and start a thread for each mail individually.

In your case if you want to do other things while waiting for the mails being sent. You could simply run the code above in a backgroundthread and when the message shows up you know work is completed.

```
public void StartMailThread()
{
    Thread myThread = new Thread(DoWork)
    {
        IsBackground = true,
        Name = "MailThread"
    };
    myThread.Start();
}
```

Although, to start a threadpool using a thread seems a bit weird to me.